# Invoke Funtion App(running locally) from Logic App(Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app

How do we invoke a function app running locally (VS) from a Logic App(in Azure)?
And also what's the best practice to debug during dev(like setting up break points..) for cloud solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about it

1. For pull-type triggers like service bus queue/subscription, there is nothing required apart ensuring connectivity to service bus from your local environment.
2. For HTTP or Event Grid triggers, you would have to expose them directly or indirectly somehow.

A direct exposure would involve setting up port forwarding on your router and use your public IP address in your HTTP action. This would require you having control over your local network, which might be the case for many corporate networks.

An indirect exposure would be to use a service like [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) or [`localtunnel`](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/).

As for debugging, locally with one of the above solutions is the simplest and efficient way for Azure Functions during development.